# Many to Many using OrmLite confusing me

Tags: android, many-to-many, android-sqlite, ormlite

I'm getting list of categories from back-end and list of posts for each category, "A category can contain MANY posts and a post can be in MANY categories" so it's Many to Many relationship. I created three classes "Category object, Post object, Category_Post object" 
Category.class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "categories")
public class Category implements Parcelable, Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long id;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String slug;
    @DatabaseField(index = true)
    private String title;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String description;
    @DatabaseField()
    private int parent;
    @DatabaseField()
    private int postCount;

    public Category() {
    }

    public Category(String slug, String title, String description, int parent, int postCount) {
        this.slug = slug;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.postCount = postCount;
    }

    public Category(long id, String slug, String title, String description, int postCount, int parent) {
        this.id = id;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.postCount = postCount;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(int parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public int getPostCount() {
        return postCount;
    }

    public void setPostCount(int postCount) {
        this.postCount = postCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o instanceof Category && o != null) {
            Category item = (Category) o;
            return id == item.getId();
        }

        return false;
    }

    public Category(final Parcel in) {
        this.id = in.readLong();
        this.slug = in.readString();
        this.title = in.readString();
        this.description = in.readString();
        this.parent = in.readInt();
        this.postCount = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeLong(id);
        parcel.writeString(slug);
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeString(description);
        parcel.writeInt(parent);
        parcel.writeInt(postCount);
    }

    public static final Creator<Category> CREATOR = new Creator<Category>() {
        @Override
        public Category createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
            return new Category(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Category[] newArray(final int size) {
            return new Category[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Post.class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "posts")
public class Post implements Parcelable, Serializable {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private long postId;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String title;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String type;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String slug;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String url;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String status;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String titlePlain;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String content;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String excerpt;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String date;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String modified;
    @DatabaseField()
    private String thumbnail;
    @DatabaseField()
    private int favorite;
    @DatabaseField()
    private int page;

    // constructors
    public Post() {}

    public Post(long postId, String type, String slug,
                    String url,String status, String title, String titlePlain,
                    String content,String excerpt, String date,
                    String modified, String thumbnail, int favorite) {
        this.postId = postId;
        this.type = type;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.url = url;
        this.status = status;
        this.title = title;
        this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
        this.content = content;
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
        this.date = date;
        this.modified = modified;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public Post(long postId, String type, String slug,
                    String url,String status, String title, String titlePlain,
                    String content,String excerpt, String date,
                    String modified, String thumbnail, int favorite, int currentPage) {
        this.postId = postId;
        this.type = type;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.url = url;
        this.status = status;
        this.title = title;
        this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
        this.content = content;
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
        this.date = date;
        this.modified = modified;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.favorite = favorite;
        this.page = currentPage;
    }

    /**
     * Write LatLng to parcel.
     */
    private Post(final Parcel in) {
        this.postId = in.readLong();

        this.title = in.readString();

        this.type = in.readString();

        this.slug = in.readString();

        this.url = in.readString();

        this.status = in.readString();


        this.titlePlain = in.readString();

        this.content = in.readString();

        this.excerpt = in.readString();

        this.date = in.readString();

        this.modified = in.readString();

        this.thumbnail = in.readString();

        this.favorite = in.readInt();

        this.page = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, final int flags) {
        out.writeLong(postId);

        out.writeString(title);

        out.writeString(type);

        out.writeString(slug);

        out.writeString(url);

        out.writeString(status);

        out.writeString(titlePlain);

        out.writeString(content);

        out.writeString(excerpt);

        out.writeString(date);

        out.writeString(modified);

        out.writeString(thumbnail);

        out.writeInt(favorite);

        out.writeInt(page);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Post> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Post>() {
        @Override
        public Post createFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
            return new Post(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Post[] newArray(final int size) {
            return new Post[size];
        }
    };

    public long getPostId() {
        return postId;
    }

    public void setPostId(long postId) {
        this.postId = postId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitlePlain() {
        return titlePlain;
    }

    public void setTitlePlain(String titlePlain) {
        this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getExcerpt() {
        return excerpt;
    }

    public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
        this.excerpt = excerpt;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(String modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public int getFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(int favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public int getCurrentPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
        this.page = currentPage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o instanceof Post && o != null) {
            Post item = (Post) o;
            return postId == item.getPostId();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

CategoryPost.class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "categoryPost")
public class CategoryPost {

    public final static String CATEGORY_ID_FIELD_NAME = "categoryId";
    public final static String POST_ID_FIELD_NAME = "postId";

    /**
     * This id is generated by the database and set on the object when it is passed to the create method. An id is
     * needed in case we need to update or delete this object in the future.
     */
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    long id;

    // This is a foreign object which just stores the id from the User object in this table.
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = CATEGORY_ID_FIELD_NAME)
    Category category;

    // This is a foreign object which just stores the id from the Post object in this table.
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = POST_ID_FIELD_NAME)
    Post post;

    CategoryPost() {
        // for ormlite
    }

    public CategoryPost(Category category, Post post) {
        this.category = category;
        this.post = post;
    }

}
```

I have three questions: How i can -

1. Create database with three classes using OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class from ORMLite library?
2. Insert categories without posts?
3. Insert post with categories?
4. Remove post from categories?
5. Remove category with all posts in it?

   Please help me to understand ORMLite library !!!

   I followed [this example](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-jdbc/tree/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/examples/manytomany) but i can't understand how i can do it.